# Редирект на url с параметрами

Tags: .htaccess

Как в файле .htaccess сделать редирект с /browse на /browse?id=2 ?

Код `Redirect 301 /browse https://site.net/browse?id=2` создает циклическую переадресацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# проверяем отсутствие переменной id со значением 2 в запросе
# "\b" в начале и конце нужны чтобы проверка не сработала на, например, pid=2 или id=22
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\bid=2\b
# сама переадресация с /browse на /browse?id=2 без передачи дополнительных переменных из оригинального запроса
RewriteRule ^browse$ /browse?id=2? [R=301,L]
```

Другой вариант

```
RewriteEngine On
# проверяем отсутствие переменных в запросе
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# сама переадресация с /browse на /browse?id=2
RewriteRule ^browse$ /browse?id=2 [R=301,L]
```

Последний вариант :)

```
RewriteEngine On
# проверяем отсутствие переменной id в запросе
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\bid=
# сама переадресация с /browse на /browse?id=2
RewriteRule ^browse$ /browse?id=2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Переадресация работает, однако страницы /browse?id=4 (либо любой другой параметр вместо 4) также переадресуют на /browse?id=2, к тому же еще добавляя %3f к концу ссылки. - /browse?id=2%3f

Comment: @faik371, добавил другой вариант с переадресацией только если отсутствуют любые GET переменные в запросе.

Comment: Второй вариант не работает вообще.

Comment: @faik371, возможно у вас `QUERY_STRING` не пустой, по этому и не работает. Предложил последний вариант с проверкой на отсутствие только переменной `id`.

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант заработал!